# KSH - Linux - ps -ef - Return code versus number of processes found

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

Regarding the *nix ps -ef command.  We have a number of shell scripts on an older AIX that use the ps -ef command to search out and see if a specific process "name" is currently running or not.  The typical usage I see it :

```
ps -ef  | grep java | grep RUDaemon | grep -v grep
rc=$?

if (( rc > 0 ))
then
    ...do process-exists stuff...
else
    ...do process-does-not-exists stuff...
fi
```

Thing is, the code doesn't appear to be working on our newer Linux...i.e., the rc now appears to be returning a simple 'status' outcome of the command itself, not the number of processes it found...Since I didn't write the original scripts, I'm not sure the original code EVER worked correctly.  But the requirements state we need to utilize native *nix commands, so I re-wrote the code in the following manner and TESTED it for both 'exist' and 'does-not-exist' conditions.

```
rc=$(ps -ef | grep java | grep RUDaemon | grep -v grep | wc -l)

if (( rc > 0 ))
then
    ...do process-exists stuff...
else
    ...do process-does-not-exists stuff...
fi
```

My question is, what is the proper usage of ps -ef to discover the number of processes running with a specific name or partial name?

tia, Adym

Comment: `rc=$?` will only provide the exit status of  `grep -v grep` . It won't help you to get the correct status of ps. Refer this link for better options. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337309/why-do-i-get-different-exit-status-for-ps-grep-in-a-script/337351

Comment: Right.  I understand that.  I'm not sure the code ever worked correctly.  But is there a recommended way to use ps -ef for finding the number of processes that have a specific name?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want not only *discover … processes running with a specific name*, but also with a specific argument, the principle usage is what you showed. But it can be optimized:

```
ps -ef | grep java | grep RUDaemon | grep -v grep
```

can be replaced with

```
ps -fCjava | grep RUDaemon
```

if indeed `java` processes with `RUDaemon` among the arguments are wanted.